# NumPy - fastest non-cryptographic collision-resistant hash

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, hash

I'm looking for the best `64-bit` (or at least `32-bit`) [hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) for [NumPy](https://numpy.org/) that has next properties:

1. It is vectorized for numpy, meaning that it should have functions for hashing all elements of any N-D numpy array.
2. It can be applied to any hashable numpy's `dtype`. For this it is enough for such hash to be able to process just raw block of bytes.
3. It is very-very fast, same like [xxhash](https://github.com/ifduyue/python-xxhash). Especially it should be fast for a lot of small inputs, like huge array of 32, 64 bit numbers or short np.str_, but also should handle other dtypes.
4. It should be [collision-resistant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_resistance). I may use just some part of bits, so any number of bits inside hash should be collision resistant too.
5. It may be (or may be not) non-crtyptographic, meaning that it is alright if it can be inverted sometimes, like `xxhash`.
6. It should produce `64-bit` integer or larger output, but if it is `32-bit` then still is OK, although not that preferable. Would be good if possible to choose to produce hashes of sizes 32, 64, 128 bits.
7. It should itself convert numpy array internally to bytes for hashing to be fast, or at least maybe there is already in numpy such conversion function that converts whole N-D array of any popular dtype to variable sequences of bytes, good if someone will tell me about this.

I would use `xxhash` mentioned by link above, if it had `numpy` arrays vectorization. But right now it is only single-object, its bindings functions accept just one block of bytes per call producing one integer output. And xxhash uses just few CPU cycles for every call on small (4, 8 bytes) input, so probably doing pure-Python loop over large array to call xxhash for every number will be very inefficient.

I need it for different things, one is probabilistic existence filters (or sets), i.e. I need to design such structure (set) that should answer with given probability (for given number `N` of elements) if a requested element is probably in the set or not. For that I want to use lower bits of hash to spread inputs across `K` buckets and each bucket additionally stores some (tweakable) number of higher bits to increase probability of good answers. Another application is [bloom filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter). And I need this set to be very fast for adding and requesting, and to be as compact as possible in memory, and handle very large number of elements.

If there is no existing good solution then maybe I can also improve `xxhash` library and create a pull request to author's repository.

Comment: If each input is a 32- or 64-bit value (or less) why would you need any hashing, the value itself (interpreted as a 32- or 64-bit unsigned integer, if you want) should do the job.

Comment: @jdehesa I forgot to mention (I'll put it in my question now) that although I need 64-bit output, still I may use just some part of bits, lower bits. And numbers itself will have lots of collisions in lower bits.

Comment: @jdehesa Also I may use it for different types of data, not only numbers, e.g. for strings of varying lengths, some are quite long, so it should handle any bytes with collision-resistance.

Comment: @jdehesa If hash has collision resistance for all its bits, e.g. 128 bits output, then this hash can be used both for 1) spreading values uniformly across some table, like hash tables. 2) identifying object almost uniquely, e.g. 128 bits collision-resistant hashes can be considered almost 100% unique for billions of different inputs.    And I need both these properties.

Comment: @jdehesa I've added to my question's text a paragraph (last but one) explaining my application purposes.

Comment: Multiply by a rather large odd (pseudo-prime) number, and take the rightmost bits.

Comment: @wildplasser xxhash in fact is faster than multiplying, so xxhash is the best fit if it had numpy adoption, xxhash has a speed faster than `memcpy`. Also I need some generic solution, for any blocks of bytes, to be able to hash any types, not only numbers. xxhash is able to process any bytes input. But thanks for pointing out nice and simple algorithm!

Comment: *faster than memcpy* And you are using python, which packs every object inside a 64 byte structure?

Comment: @wildplasser I use numpy and numpy is able to directly copy whole memory into raw array, in other words when working with 32/64 ints numpy is almost as fast as regular `C/C++`. Hence hashing is also needed to be fast.

Comment: @wildplasser BTW, you mentioned that a good hash would be multiplying by prime number and taking lower bits. In general it is not collision resistant, e.g. if you have a sequence of numbers like 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256 all of them being multiplied by any number give same zeros in lower bits. From hash I expect to mix data well so that hash looks like pseudo random number for all inputs. Probably similar to your suggestion a good hash would be multiplying by 64-bit any random fixed number, obtaining 128-bit result, then taking modulus maximal 64-bit safe prime, this should be quite good hash.

Comment: Of course it is not collision resistant. You cant hash X bits into fewer tham X bits without collisions.

Comment: It should be quite straight forward to create another interface to xxhash using cython, or some boiler plate code in C which does the looping+ Ctypes for wrapping. It would be good if you add a complete reproduceable example using python-xxhash and than ask for another wrapper which works on whole arrays.

Comment: @max9111 Probably that's what I will do if there is no good-enough ready-made solution. I'm not insisting that `xxhash` specifically should be used, I'm just saying that if such speed was achieved by it then at least good solutions for my problem should have comparable speed.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for this:

```
from xxhash import xxh3_64

def hash_numpy(array):
    return xxh3_64(array.tobytes()).digest()
```

I don't think you can get much better.
My crappy benchmark says that this hashes 200 million floats per second on my crappy laptop (old i3 CPU).